# Update images link to their own URL

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I've recently migrated a blog from Blogger to a fresh WordPress install and all the content was transferred successfully. However, I've noticed all images attached to posts are linked to their original URLs at Blogger.

I'd like to update all images hrefs to their own WordPress URL, but I'm not sure how to do it.

All images are linked like this:

`<a href="https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-gZsYD5y6Uyo/WyEjtVFQOgI/AAAAAAAAd74/-73I4Y3OrCEIc7yr4Ca1cmhKrNHqdtjyQCLcBGAs/s1600/Dicas%2Bde%2Bhoteis%2Bem%2Bsetubal.jpg" src="http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/Dicasdehoteisemsetubal.jpg"/></a>`

And I'd like them to be like this:

`<a href="http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/Dicasdehoteisemsetubal.jpg" src="http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/Dicasdehoteisemsetubal.jpg"/></a>`

Can you help me?

Comment: Where are you getting the URLs from? Is a database driving your content generation or did you manually link the images on the Blogger instance?

Comment: @brae This blog is not actually mine, I believe these images were manually linked on Blogger.

Answer (score 0):

Well referencing images on WP can sometimes prove to be trick using their own library as they are not exactly showing the real pathway. you can try as they suggest on codex : [Using Images](https://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Images).

Or you can upload the images on a public server like Imgur: https://imgur.com/upload and get the image link for referencing in your code.

Good Luck. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can update the links manually through post editor or use a plugin like velvet-blues-update-urls

Comment: I gave velvet blue a shot, but these links have no pattern to match the format ```/wp-content/uploads/year/month/```